# Timing sounds off, how do I confirm this?

Tags: rough-idle, timing, cold-start

This is a 1997 vauxhall corsa B.

I recently had the timing belt changed, by a professional mechanic that I have lost touch with.

I find that after not using the vehicle for a week or two, after starting the engine, the engine sounds rough. It doesn't sound like a smooth-running engine. Sometimes it does a double-take when turning the ignition key over(like the penalty-taker, in European football, does a pause to delay his kick to get the goalie to dive too soon).

This rough running sound is less pronounced with frequent use of the vehicle, but it does still sound a bit rough, and although I'm not an experienced mech', I suspect it may have something to do with the timing.

How can I check to see if the timing is off? For instance can I check the air/fuel mixture? I don't have one of those electronic readers.

Comment: This could be timing, there are many other causes for a rough running engine. It sounds much more likely to be ignition or fuel related than timing.

Answer (score 4):

When changing the timing belt, it is the valve timing that can become displaced if the belt is not put back in the correct position.  To accurately check this is a simple visual check.  However, to do this visual check will require the disassembly of some engine components to be able to see the position of the pulleys that the belt runs on.  This is not a quick task.  There will be marks (pointers) on the engine that all the pulleys need to point at at the same time.  If one of the alignment marks do not align, then the valve timing will be out.

To check the electrical ignition timing, you will need a strobe light.  The light flashes every time the spark plug fires.  There will be marking on the crank shaft pulley that need to align with markings on the engine casing each time the light flashes.  This test usually doesn't much (if any) disassembly.  However this test is no indication of the valve timing status.

Depending on the engine design, it is possible that changing the belt could have knocked out either the valve timing or the ignition timing.

Timing issues could show up using exhaust gas analyser, but out-of-spec exhaust readings could be due to many other reasons, not just timing.